# How to close select class dropdown when selected outside?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

So my 4 dropdowns are as follow:

```
<select class="form-dropdown field" name="employee_id" id="employee_id" required="">
        <option value=""> Select Employee ID *</option>
        
        <option value="23137">Sydney Ross ( 23137 )</option>
        
        <option value="E00474">Andy Sandberg ( E00474 )</option>
   
        
      </select>
       <!-- <input type="text" id="employee_id" name="employee_id" placeholder="Employee ID" class="field text-field last-name-field" required style="border: 1px solid #ccc;"> -->

    <span id="span_month" title="">
    <div id="list1" class="dropdown-check-list" tabindex="1" style="">
      <div class="custom-dropdown">
        <span class="anchor" onclick="getElements(list1)">Select Months</span>
          <div class="options">
          <ul id="list1_items" class="items visible" name="month" style="display: block;"><li><input type="checkbox" name="month" value="4" id="4"><label for="4">Apr</label></li><li><input type="checkbox" name="month" value="5" id="5"><label for="5">May</label></li><li><input type="checkbox" name="month" value="6" id="6"><label for="6">Jun</label></li></ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </span>
    <span id="span_quarter" title="">
      <div id="list2" class="dropdown-check-list" tabindex="100" style="">
        <div class="custom-dropdown">
        <span class="anchor" onclick="getElements(list2)">Select Quarter</span>
        <div class="options">
        <ul id="list2_items" class="items visible" name="quarter" style="display: none;"><li><input type="checkbox" name="quarter" value="1" id="1" disabled=""><label for="1"> Apr - Jun (Quarter 1)</label></li></ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</span>

<span id="span_year">
  <select class="form-dropdown field" name="year" id="list3_items" required="">
      <option value=""> Select Year *</option>
      <option value="2021"> 2021-2022 </option>
  </select>
</span>
```

So when I click the outside of the dropdown it should auto close.

```
$('html').click(function() {
  $('#list1_items').hide();
});

$('#list1').click(function(event) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $('#list2_items').hide();
  // $('#list3_items').hide();
});
$('html').click(function() {
  $('#list2_items').hide();
});

$('#list2').click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  $('#list1_items').hide();
  // $('#list3_items').hide();
});
```

I tried this solution but it is working perfectly fine on Windows but not on linux machine, I know javascript is done by browser and has no effect of the OS, but this is the issue I am facing, I tried a lot of solutions but nothing is working.
Please if someone can help me.

It is showing like this:
[the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuHOe.png)
Thankyou.

Comment: HTML does that by itself. Can you describe whats wrong? Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/vwaebpc5/

Comment: Look I added the screenshot to show you the issue

Comment: it works fine for me, dont need any JS to close it. https://jsfiddle.net/Alexisgarci/aq64tuh0/

Comment: For me it doesn't working, I dont know why, actually it is working fine on windows but not on linux